# If x = 75 x = 100 Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, lambda, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have this formula in Google Sheets, I need that if the result is 70 this value is changed to 100, I'm not really sure about how to do it

```
=SUM((VLOOKUP(D7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$D$3),(VLOOKUP(E7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$E$3),(VLOOKUP(F7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$F$3),(VLOOKUP(G7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$G$3),(VLOOKUP(H7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$H$3),(VLOOKUP(I7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$I$3),(VLOOKUP(J7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$J$3),(VLOOKUP(K7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$K$3),(VLOOKUP(L7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$L$3),(VLOOKUP(M7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$M$3))
```

SOLUTION:

it will be like this?

```
=IF(SUM((VLOOKUP(D7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$D$3),(VLOOKUP(E7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$E$3),(VLOOKUP(F7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$F$3),(VLOOKUP(G7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$G$3),(VLOOKUP(H7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$H$3),(VLOOKUP(I7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$I$3),(VLOOKUP(J7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$J$3),(VLOOKUP(K7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$K$3),(VLOOKUP(L7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$L$3),(VLOOKUP(M7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$M$3))) => 70, 100, =SUM((VLOOKUP(D7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$D$3),(VLOOKUP(E7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$E$3),(VLOOKUP(F7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$F$3),(VLOOKUP(G7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$G$3),(VLOOKUP(H7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$H$3),(VLOOKUP(I7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$I$3),(VLOOKUP(J7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$J$3),(VLOOKUP(K7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$K$3),(VLOOKUP(L7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$L$3),(VLOOKUP(M7,Sheet1!$P$7:$Q$12,2,TRUE)*$M$3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, IF(x=70, 100, x))(SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(D7:M7, Sheet1!P7:Q12, 2)*D3:M3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the entire thing in an If statement, where 'formula' stands for the entirety of the formula you posted.

```
=If(formula = 70, 100, formula)
```

Comment: Or in Excel using LET: `=LET(x,formula,if(x=70,100,x))`

Comment: update the post and see if that was what you mean please